# Solving system of equations (the naive way?).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

So lets say there is a system of equation with 2 equation and 2 variables:

$a_1x +  b_1y   = c_1 ...(i) $    
$a_2x +  b_2y   = c_2 ...(ii) $

One way to solve this equation is to use the **cross-multiplication** formula (I will skip writing the formula because it can just be checked from Wiki).The way the formula is derived is like this:
(1) multiply $(i)$ by $a_2$ and $(ii)$ by $a_1$ 
(2) because on both equations we have $a_1a_2x$ we can just do $ (i)-(ii)$ to cancel $x$ and solve for $y$

After seeing this , I wondered if it is possible to do this with a system of equation with 3 equation and 3 variables.

$a_1x +  b_1y + c_1z   = d_1 ...(i)  $    
$a_2x +  b_2y + c_2z  =  d_2 ...(ii) $    
$a_3x +  b_3y + c_3z  =  d_3 ...(iii) $

This is what I have done so far.

(1) multiply $(i)$ by $a_2$ and and $(ii)$ by $a_1$ 
(2) because on both equations we have $a_1a_2x$ we can just do $ (i)-(ii)$ to cancel $x$ and get a "new equation" with two variables : $y$ and $z$ 
(3) Do the same thing with $(i)$ and $(iii)$, cancel $x$ and get a another "new equation" with two variables : $y$ and $z$ ( this time , multiply $(i)$ by $a_3$ and and $(ii)$ by $a_1$ ) 
(4) treat the equations gotten from step (2) and (3) like a system of equation with 2 equation and 2 variables and solve for $y$ and $z$ .With that , solve for $x$

I have skipped the process for a system of equation wit 4 variables , but it seems like similarly, I can reduce it to a system of equation with 3 variables  , solve for the 3 variables and solve for the last one manually .So if I know the formula for solving a system of $n$ variables , I can use it to solve a system of $(n+1)$ variable. Maybe I can chain up solutions like this to get solutions to any system of  linear equation?

Now I have two question,
(1) Is there something wrong with this technique , if there is , where is it? 
(2) If this technique is valid , then , can this technique be generalized or extended to system of equations with $n$ equation and $n$ variables?

Comment: You may be interested in **Gauss elimination** and **Kramer's rule**, since both are based on similar ideas.

Comment: What you’re doing is called row reduction. It is a very good way to solve linear systems.

Comment: To be frank, I didn't really study linear algebra (only vectors and matrices).So it will be kind of hard for me to find an exact relation between my naive technique and modern methods like Gaussian elimination.It would definitely help to show me why they are the same idea.And also,is my weird approach for this problem anywhat useful for understanding things like determinants?

Comment: What you are doing by multiplying and then subtracting the two equations from one another is completely valid, and the general form for this method goes by the name [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).